# How to get SOAP user name in WCF Service when using UserNamePasswordValidator?

Tags: security, wcf

A SOAP request is made to my WCF service. How can I access the user name used in the request's `Envelope.Header.Security.UserNameToken.Username` field?
I am using a custom [UserNamePasswordValidator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-use-a-custom-user-name-and-password-validator) to check the credentials.

Answer (score 0):

In my case `System.ServiceModel.ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity.Name` held the user name (from the request's SOAP header) used in the [UserNamePasswordValidator.Validate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.selectors.usernamepasswordvalidator.validate?view=netframework-4.8#System_IdentityModel_Selectors_UserNamePasswordValidator_Validate_System_String_System_String_) method. It can be accessed in the WCF Service class/method.

```
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public Response ServiceMethod(Request request)
        {
            string userName = System.ServiceModel.ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity.Name;
            // ...
        }
    }
```